# iOS Documents with UIFileSharingEnabled

Tags: iphone, ios, sharing, documents

My iPhone app uses a sqlite3 database for storing the data that it generates.  This data needs to persist, and I need to make sure the user cannot damage it.  I also want to allow the user to export data as text/csv files, these would be shared through iTunes.  I plan to put the database in the Library folder, write the CSV files to the Doucments folder, and turn on `UIFileSharingEnabled`.

Is there anyway I can stop the user from adding files to my apps Documents directory through iTunes?

If not, it is acceptable practice to have my app delete any files that it did not create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can stop the user from adding files to my apps Documents directory through iTunes?

No

> If not, it is acceptable practice to have my app delete any files that it did not create?

Of course not. Why do you want to do this anyway? If you use the documents directory for exporting only, simply ignore anything that's inside.

Comment: Thanks - it just seems messy to have the possibility of files there that my program doesn't know what to do with.  I guess that also means I should take care to not overwrite anything when creating exports.